# Using JavaScript to change an XML to use in JSON API

Tags: javascript, json, xml, escaping

I am using Rhino JavaScript and I am looking to manipulate an XML so I can use it in a JSON field to send via API. I am looking to do the following escaping:

```
CFLR (new Line) replace with \r\n
" replace with \" 
\ replace with \/
```

So if I had following XML for example

```
<Data>
    <Employee name="John" Surname="Smith">
</Data>
```

I would want it in this form:

```
<Data>\r\n<Employee>name=\"John\"Surname=\"Smith\">\r\n<\/Data>
```

Can anyone help with this? I have thought about it I know the function .replace exists in JavaScript but I am stuck on how I would replace the new line and how the .replace would work performance wise working with large XML's.

Thanks, I would appreciate the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's one way to do it:

```js
var xml = "<Data>\r\n<Employee name=\"John\" Surname=\"Smith\">\r\n</Data>";

console.log(xml);

String.prototype.replaceAll = function(search, replacement) {
    var target = this;
    return target.split(search).join(replacement);
};
xml = xml.replaceAll("\"", "\\\"").replaceAll("\r\n", "\\r\\n");

console.log(xml);
```

Comment: could someone maybe also explain to me what the function does in the code snippet. 
i.e. what is var target = this;
and why do we split and join it ?
Thanks

Comment: `this` is the String itself, the subject of the replace call. Splitting and joining is a simple trick to do replacements; Say you want to replace 'C' with 'c' in "ABCDE". split('C') turns it into `["AB", "DE"]`; join('c') turns the array back into a String: `"ABcDE"`